# Custom intellij plugin to trigger function like textChange()

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am writing a custom plugin for intellij.

This plugin listens to port. When receiving specific information, it should trigger to scan text, like `textChange().`

When java file has been modified, Inspection plugin will inspect all file again to find some errors or warnings. But I want to trigger inspecting by my program, instead of modifying

How can I trigger this event?

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger to scan text"?

Comment: When java file has been modified, **Inspection** plugin will inspect all file again to find some errors or warnings. But I want to trigger inspecting by my program, instead of modifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force rehighlighting of a file, use `DaemonCodeAnalyzer.getInstance(project).restart(file)`.